# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined error, yet still renders the correct data

Tags: angular

For some reason I'm getting an error thrown on when trying to determine the length of a json object.  The error is: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined and center's on this line:

```
<div>{{ (locations | filter: query).length }}</div>
```

The odd thing is, it's working and showing me the length of the object through and that number is accurate.

The code in question is in my component.html file:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-6 ml-auto">
          <h5 class="text-center"><div ng-repeat="locations in locations | filter: query"></div>
            <div>{{ (locations | filter: query).length }}</div>
            <br>
            <small class="text-center">Total Locations</small>
          </h5>
        </div>
```

component.ts:

```
    import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm, FormBuilder } from '@angular/forms';
import { Organizations } from '../../../../_models/organizations';
import { AlertifyService } from '../../../../_services/alertify.service';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from '../../../../_services/auth.service';
import { OrganizationService } from '../../../../_services/Organization.service';
import { LocationService } from '../../../../_services/location.service';
import { Locations } from '../../../../_models/locations';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-organization-detail',
  templateUrl: './organization-detail.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./organization-detail.component.scss']
})
export class OrganizationDetailComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('editForm', {static: true}) editForm: NgForm;
  searchTerm: string;
  organizations: Organizations;
  locations: Locations;
  currentDate = new Date();
  isActive = false;
  query: number;
  p: number;

  @HostListener('window:beforeunload', ['$event'])
  unloadNotidication($event: any) {
    if (this.editForm.dirty) {
      $event.returnValue = true;
    }
  }

  constructor(private organizationService: OrganizationService, private alertify: AlertifyService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private fb: FormBuilder,
    private router: Router, private authService: AuthService, private locationService: LocationService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getOrgLocations();

    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.organizations = data['organization'];
    });
  }

  loadOrganization() {
    this.organizationService.GetOrganization(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((organization: Organizations) => {
      this.organizations = organization;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  getOrgLocations() {
    this.locationService.getOwnedLocations(+this.route.snapshot.params['id']).subscribe((locations: Locations) => {
      this.locations = locations;
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }

  updateClient() {
    this.organizationService.updateOrganization(this.organizations.id, this.organizations).subscribe(next => {
      this.alertify.success('Client updated successfully');
      this.editForm.reset(this.loadOrganization());
    }, error => {
      this.alertify.error(error);
    });
  }
}
```

Any ideas on what may be causing this?  I cant see why the error is thrown, yet it properly renders the correct data at the same time

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's because for a few cycles `locations` is undefined before it becomes defined, just do this:

```
<div *ngIf="locations">{{ (locations | filter: query).length }}</div>
```

or

```
<div>{{ (locations | filter: query)?.length }}</div>
```

or initialize `locations` to some sensible default. depends on what your needs are.

Comment: Thanks Bryan60.  This did the trick. I did some reading on the ngIf vs the safe navigation operator (ad I'm just learning to code myself right now) and it looks like using the ngIf statement will probably work out the best as it wont render the div statement if null is returned.  

Thanks again for your insight.

Answer (score 0):

According to your code, you're getting the list of locations via some API call, which will eventually take some time.

What's happening is that Angular is trying to render "locations" even before it is initialised.

You can try either putting a conditional in your html:

Or just try putting a breakpoint / log in your filter. You'll get to know what's being passed.

Hope this helps.